# Sonarqube Jenkins integration error, no analysis has been performed

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

I'm trying to integrate Sonar analysis into my Jenkins. I have set up a multi module configuration, and I think the analysis runs as it should, based on the jenkins build logs.

```
INFO: Analysis report generated in 234ms, dir size=774 KB
INFO: Analysis reports compressed in 94ms, zip size=199 KB
INFO: Analysis report uploaded in 74ms
INFO: ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse 
http://localhost:9000/dashboard/index/perso
INFO: Note that you will be able to access the updated dashboard once the 
server has processed the submitted analysis report
INFO: More about the report processing at http://localhost:9000/api/ce/task?
id=AVwVnhRax2vtJSkdxag8
INFO: Task total time: 9.919 s
INFO: ---------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION SUCCESS
```

But when I head over to the Sonar dashboard, all I get is this.

```
No analysis has been performed since creation. The only available section is the configuration.
```

I checked out the Sonar log, where it shows the error but sadly I couldn't solve the issue based on that.
Error: https://pastebin.com/N50RhBT3

The final cause was an SSL connection exception, but since both servers are running local, why would there be SSL?

Used versions: Sonar plugin 2.6.1, Sonarqube server 6.3.1, Sonarqube Scanner 3.0.3.778. , Jenkins 2.59

Thanks,
peter

Comment: That error was in the server log? What about the background task processing log?

Comment: Could you point me to the log file? The above comes from sonar\logs\ce.log

Comment: I opened the logs from the dashnboard as it shows here https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Background+Tasks. It shows the same error.

Comment: Check also sonar\logs\sonar.log

Comment: It hasn't got updated during the process. Last log line is --  INFO  app[][o.s.application.App] SonarQube is up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was basically a java not found error. Due to an annoying Jenkins bug, previously I had to reinstall Java. This change only partially went through sonarqube, and it caused the error above. The solution was pointing sonar to that java_home with the wrapper config file.